# Why `fgets()` need a *str but `getline()` need a **str parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, io

Both of them could get a line from a stream.

The definition is below:

```
 ssize_t
 getline(char ** restrict linep, size_t * restrict linecapp, FILE * restrict stream);
```

And

```
 char *
 fgets(char * restrict str, int size, FILE * restrict stream);
```

Why does `getline` need `a pointer to a pointer to char`, instead of using `a pointer to char` like what `fgets`do?

And does the two expression below equivalent？

(1)

```
char *str = NULL
read = getline (&str, &len, fp);
```

(2)

```
char *str = NULL
read = fgets (str, &len, fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

getline() can, if you pass in a pointer to NULL, allocate its own memory (which you must later `free`).  fgets *must* be passed an existing buffer.

getline needs the extra indirection so it can modify the pointer to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`getline`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html) will allocate a buffer for you if you pass it a pointer to a `char*` which is `null`.

As for your second question: No. The `fgets` example will likely result in a SEGV. [`fgets`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fgets.3.html) expects the buffer to actually exist.